# Link and show domain to public ip on EC2 instance Amazon

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, dns, wampserver

I'm quite newbie in this area, but I've tried to run a wampserver in my EC2 instance. It has worked very well.

Now, I have a domain and I try to link it to my public ip, and it works, but users type "www.mydomain.com" and automaticaly URL is transformed in public ip, so it's not pretty.

What do I need to show always my domain? I've tried with Route53 but I couldn't achieve :(

Could anybody give me some clue or any link to learn about this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Your web server is not configured to know the correct hostname for the site and is redirecting the browser back to the IP.  In the server logs, you should see a 301 or 302 redirect.  The fix depends on your web server software but with wamp, I assume apache?

Comment: Yes, Apache. Where I shoud find?